# JQuery Context Menu, ajax and Load Function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using Jquery Context Menu and have linked this with an ajax function to call a php script which updates a database. After this, I want the Ajax script to refresh the context menu element (a table) so that it reflects the changes made to the database. I have done this by placing everything in a div and i'm trying to use the javascript load function to call the page again.

The first time I select something from the context menu, everything works fine - the database updates, the div refreshes and context menu still works on the newly refreshed content. However, if I then use the context menu again, the table updates but the div will not refresh. Can anyone see if there is a problem with the below code... my guess would be there is something stopping the success function on the ajax from running more than once but I have no idea what. Here is what I have so far:

```
$(function(){
    $('#the-node').contextMenu({
        selector: '.emptycell', 
        trigger: 'left',
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key + " on " + $(this).attr("id");
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "inc/updatestatus.php",
                data: 'id='+$(this).attr("id")+'&status='+key,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $('#the-node').load('inc/get_dashboard.php');

                }
            });
        },
        items: {
            "s0": {name: "Status: 0", icon: "red"},
            "s1": {name: "Status: 1", icon: "blue"},
            "s2": {name: "Status: 2", icon: "green"}
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your get_dashboard.php is the problem rather than the JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution was to add `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` to the function incase anyone ever needs this :)